# Command line argument issues

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I have a batch file which uses an external program called ASET.exe (http://www.pement.org/sed/bat_env.htm) to set values to variables. This was used as it has some advanced capabilities than the normal SET command. ASET can change the given string to different formats and then assign it to it. It has functions like UPPER(), Fread(), Lower(), left().

```
c:\test> aset var := left('asdf',2)
```

the above statement assigns "as" to Variable "var". But the problem is it will work only in win 98 or before machines. It will not work in win NT or in XP or 2008. So, I decided to write a small program like ASET in c# which supports some small number of functions. I am reading those commands as Command line arguments and parsing them, and then using a for loop and switch case, I am able to achieve the desired result to some extent. But I am not able to parse properly for all types of commands.

For Eg: I cannot parse this properly:

```
aset var := left(upper(fsdsf),2).
```

My question is that 
What is the correct procedure for parsing commandline arguments? How to distinguish function names, various switches, operators ? Using "switch" is the only solution to call a function based on the input string ?

This is my Grammar file

```
grammar sra;

options {

  language = Java;
  output = AST;
}

start returns [String res]: expression 
{
$res=$expression.res;
System.out.println("value equals at start: "+$expression.text+$res);
} ;

expression returns [String res]
: Identifier Assignop statement
{$res=$statement.res;
System.out.println("value equals at ecpression: "+$statement.text+" "+$res);}
;

statement returns [String res]
  : function {$res=$function.res;
  System.out.println("value equals at statement: "+$function.text+" "+$res);}

  //|function Plus function
  //|function Plus Identifier
  //|Identifier
  //|Identifier Plus Identifier
  ;


   function returns [String res]
  : e=upper {$res=$e.res;
  System.out.println("value equals at function: "+$e.text+" "+$res);}  
  ;
upper returns [String res]
  : e=Upper '(' b=arguments   ')'
  {
  System.out.println("argum before conver "+$b.text);
  $res= ($b.text).toUpperCase();
  System.out.println("value equals at upper: "+$e.text+" "+"Arguments="+$b.text+" "+$res); }

  ;
arguments  returns [String res]     
                :   e1=Identifier   {$res=$e1.text;}
                |  function  {$res=$function.res;} 
                ;


Upper : 'upper';
Lower : 'lower';

Identifier  :  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*;
Assignop :':=' ;

Lparen  : '(';
Rparen  : ')';
Plus  : '+';
WS  : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+{$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

Now how to achieve functionality like var := upper(upper(fsf)) ?? I am getting output as UPPER(FSF)..

Comment: The reason it doesn't work in XP or above is because it needs to write to the parent process' environment block. Rather than do this why not learn PowerShell or even VBScript with WSF?

Comment: But I have many such batch files which uses ASET. I dont want to change all those files

Comment: I got the solution. I chanegd the following line
$res= ($b.text).toUpperCase();
into as follows 
$res= ($b.res).toUpperCase();

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the command line arguments however you want. The usage you're suggesting isn't a typical usage for command line arguments, so there isn't one "correct" procedure for what you want to do.

You seem to have your own grammer in mind, (could be based on pascal I guess), so you need to find or write a parser and evaluater for your grammer.  At the one end of the scale is something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org), or you could get somewhere with [sprache](http://code.google.com/p/sprache/).

Also might be worth taking a look at http://commandline.codeplex.com/ for some ideas on parsing and processing command line parameters (although I doubt this will suffice for your requirements).

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. Is my requirement so complex ? I will try to learn ANTLR and use it :)

Comment: It looks like you want to be able to evaluate expressions passed in from the command line - it's possible that you can get away with a simple parser, but without knowing the syntax you want to support (I don't know what the syntax for aset is), I can't be sure - you might be able to do something with the Boo compiler / interpreter

Comment: I am really sorry for the delay in the reply. I was vary busy. In this period I tried to learn ANTLR and I am able to understand basics of it.

Comment: I created a small grammar file. It has only one function . UPPER
Upper(asdf) returns ASDF 
Now I want the functionality like upper(upper(asdf)) returning ASDF.. 
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 98 has been out of support for 6 years, and so has ASET.

You might see if "Take Command" (4NT) will do what you want, but otherwise I think a VirtualBox with FreeDOS might be your best bet.